# Usage of "as" in English

Tags: meaning, grammar

Considering the sentence "Solitude is about abandoning the self as the focus of understanding", what does “abandon sth as sth” mean and if I rewrited this sentence using the sentence that "Solitude is about abandoning the self, for it is the focus of understanding.", would I be wrong?

Comment: Think of 'We must abandon communism as [being] a political system that benefits everybody'. / Your rewrite obviously changes the meaning; you're rewriting '"Solitude is about abandoning the self as it is the focus of understanding" (which doesn't really make sense in any case).

Comment: Please, be clear.

Comment: 'Solitude is essentially stopping regarding the self as the focus of understanding.' is probably what this is meant to convey. With a less obscure sentence, 'We must stop relying on harsh penalties as being the way to solve the drugs problem' means that what we must stop relying on (abandon) is 'harsh penalties as the way to solve the drugs problem'. NOT 'harsh penalties – for they are the way to solve the drugs problem.'

Answer (score 0):

> Solitude is about abandoning the self as the focus of understanding.

This means to give up the notion that in order to obtain solitude, you need to abandon the idea that self is the focus of understanding.

It's possible that, in order to obtain solitude, you should instead accept the idea that the pursuit of knowledge is the focus of understanding.

That has quite a different meaning than:

> Solitude is about abandoning the self, for it is the focus of understanding.

The original statement doesn't claim that the self should be abandoned. It just claims that the self shouldn't be the focus of understanding.

For instance, the original sentence *might* be true if both of the following are true:

1. You don't abandon the self but keep holding onto it.
2. Even while holding onto the self, you acknowledge that the focus of understanding is something else.

In other words, **the self as the focus of understanding** ≠ **the self**. Abandoning one is not the same thing as abandoning the other.

Comment: So I can say "the self as the focus of understanding" is a phrase? I have understood the sentence now but the using of as in this way is stranger to me, could you explain it to me?

Comment: @AhmetÖztürk Yes, it's a noun phrase. It answers the question: What is solitude about abandoning?

Comment: May you also answer this question: "Some scholars reject parts of the Gospel as untrue. A design team rejected the Aerospike concept as too risky. Gibson rejected the idea as ‘absurd’. Considering this 3 sentences, what does 'reject sth as sth' mean? Do these sentences have more meaning than one?"?

Comment: @AhmetÖztürk I would say that **as** here is closely aligned with **because they believed (them / it) to be**.